Why does ShellExecuteA sometimes not complete an action?
I'm using RAD Studio C++ Builder.
I am not yet using their clang compiler (long story), so my code cannot use C++17 functions.
(Since this is a standard VCL application, I believe CoInitialize is run automatically)
I'm trying to make a shortcut (button) to open "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager", from within one of my applications.
I'm using some code that's been working to do open applications for years, however, it's not working with :

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe (this is taken from The administrative tools shortcut)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe (same thing without variables)

I have checked and the File does exist.
This is the code I'm using:
void __fastcall TLaunch::OpenApplication ( const AnsiString& Operation
                                         , const AnsiString& Location
                                         , const AnsiString& FileName
                                         , const AnsiString& Parameters
                                         )
{
    HWND       hwnd         = NULL;
    LPCSTR     lpOperation  = Operation.c_str();                                
    LPCSTR     lpFile       = FileName.c_str();                                 
    LPCSTR     lpParameters = Parameters.c_str();                               
    LPCSTR     lpDirectory  = Location.c_str();                                 
    INT        nShowCmd     = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    HINSTANCE  AppHandle    = ShellExecuteA ( hwnd
                                            , lpOperation
                                            , lpFile
                                            , lpParameters
                                            , lpDirectory
                                            , nShowCmd
                                            );
    INT_PTR IP_Handle       =  INT_PTR(AppHandle);
    switch (IP_Handle)
    {
        case 0                      : ShowMessage (L"Operating System Out of Memmory");
                                      break;
        case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND   : ShowMessage (L"File Not Found"); 
                                      break;
        case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND   : ShowMessage (L"Path Not Found"); 
                                      break;
        case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT       : ShowMessage (L"The .exe file is invalid"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED    : ShowMessage (L"Access Denied"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE : ShowMessage (L"The file name association is incomplete");      
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_DDEBUSY         : ShowMessage (L"Other DDE transactions are being processed"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_DDEFAIL         : ShowMessage (L"DDE transaction failed"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT      : ShowMessage (L"DDE request timed out"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND     : ShowMessage (L"DLL not found"); 
                                      break;
        //case SE_ERR_FNF             :    duplicate of FILE NOT FOUND
        case SE_ERR_NOASSOC         : ShowMessage (L"No Application Association"); 
                                      break;
        case SE_ERR_OOM             : ShowMessage (L"ShellExecute : Not Enough Memory"); 
                                      break;
        //case SE_ERR_PNF             :    duplicate of PATH NOT FOUND
        case SE_ERR_SHARE           : ShowMessage (L"ShellExecute : Sharing Violation"); 
                                      break;
    }
//    if (IP_Handle < 32)
//    {
//        DWORD ShellExecuteError = GetLastError();
//        ShowMessage (UnicodeString(ShellExecuteError));
//    };
}

// This Returns File Not Found
    OpenApplication       ("open"
                          ,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\"
                          ,"InetMgr.exe"
                          ,""
                          );
// This Returns File Not Found
    OpenApplication       ("open"
                          ,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\"
                          ,"C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\InetMgr.exe"
                          ,""
                          );

When I looked at the Administrative tools shortcut to get the file details the target did not include any quotes or Parameters, so I've not included any within my call.
I also tried running C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe manually from a CMD opened without Admin rights. The app was displayed, so I shouldn't need to use "runas". I'm therefore a bit confused as to why this does not work through ShellExecuteA. (Like I said, this code happily opens other applications).
Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?
or why this App behaves differently from everything else I ask ShellExecuteA to open?
Perhaps??? this might be related to why I had problems signing my apps using ShellExecuteA?
Opening the App is my question , this is just something that might be related. If I use signtool.exe installed from the MS Windows 10 SDK to sign my applications, I have to use a command line script similar to the one below
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe" sign /a /f "C:\Development\( RESOURCE )\_Certs\V12.pfx" /p "PasswordExample" /d "Company Name : App" /tr "http://timestamp.digicert.com" /td sha256 /fd sha256 /v "R:\(Distribute)\V12.1.1 [24-05]\(2024-05-03)\ACMS V1211.2405 (x86-Distro)\MyApp.exe" 

However, if I run this using ShellExecuteA no digital signature gets assigned to my applications. If I instead save the (exact) text I sent to ShellExecuteA to a batch file and run it manually, no errors are received and the the app ends up with a digital signature. I'm baffled.com 
(I deleted my attempts at the ShellExecute code signing thing ages ago so I can't provide any broken examples)
Any help you can provide will be gratefully received.
Cheers :)
--------- 14/05/2024 -- UPDATES --------- 
Following everybodies feedback (thank you all)
I am updating my code to provide some diagnostics, per Remy's request.
HINSTANCE AppHandle = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I also included GetLastError() , this started returning 0 after the switch statement was added, so It's now commented out (it had been returning 2)
Notes :

I have always been using \ in my strings , the path strings I posted were taken directly from my debuggers output. Apologies for not picking this up
This is a 32 bit app as I am not using the clang enhanced compiler
I am using ShellExecute, because I don't know any better (and it's not caused me any problems in the past).
I will look at CreateProcess a bit later (but I suspect it won't help).
Per someone's suggestions to try using forward slashes instead, I have now. This did not make anything work (it's also a linux thing).

I have tried what someone has marked as "the solution" (I used an exact copy). somehow it's still failing [Scratches head]
I tested it with launching one of my own applications, as per my previous experiences. This worked without issues.
I added my switch statement in to the answers code. It's also reporting "File not Found".
I'm an admin on this machine. The folder permissions (users) show "Read & Execute" + "List contents". The File persmissions (users) show "Read & Execute". Which I guess suggests it shouldn't be a permissions thing.
    UnicodeString TFile = UnicodeString(FileName);
    bool          found = FileExists(TFile);
    if (found)
    {
        ShowMessage (L"Found "+TFile);
    }

I added the above code to the provided solution/function. FileExists returns a value of false (which is why I think CreateProcess won't help).
Since this makes no sense to me. I wondered if this was machine related. I then tried again on a second Machine. Still no Dice. So it's failing on Win 10, & Win 2019 Server. both fully patched.

running the following (directly providing values) also fails!
    HINSTANCE AppHandle = ShellExecuteA( NULL
                                       , "open"
                                       , "C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\InetMgr.exe"
                                       , ""
                                       , ""
                                       , SW_SHOWNORMAL
                                       );

Thanks for everyones help, but it looks like I might need to admit defeat on this one :( 
I'm likely to keep going in the background trying a few different things (CreateProcess & SellExecuteEx), but ultimately, it seems like this app has some other wordly property that makes it invisible to RAD Studio :( 
If I do find a working solution I will post it here.
--------- 14/05/2024 -- FEEDBACK on my aside --------- 
Since I was already grappling with ShellExecuteA I took another look at my Digital signing issue. While I've not yet managed to sign an app 'directly' through the use of ShellExecuteA yet. I have found that if I use it to run the batch file I was creating to bulk update some files. I can at least sign my apps indirectly
AnsiString lpFile     = "Sign All [STD] Files.bat";
AnsiString lpLocation = DestinationFolder;
AnsiString lpBatch    = lpLocation + lpFile;
ShellExecuteA   ( NULL                        // HWND    hwnd
                , "open"                      // LPCWSTR lpOperation
                , lpBatch.c_str()             // LPCWSTR lpFile
                , ""                          // LPCWSTR lpParameters
                , lpLocation.c_str()          // LPCWSTR lpDirectory
                , SW_SHOWNORMAL               // INT     nShowCmd
                );

--------- 18/05/2024 -- more FEEDBACK --------- 
So, a few people questioned why I used ShellExecute rather than CreateProcess. The answer was "I don't know any better", but it looks like ShellExecute may have been what I needed to use anyway...
I now have some code for working with CreateProcess (it works with the borland compatible compiler). I'm in no way saying it's good code (do check it before you use it). It works for me, so it may work for you.

I've used it to run the batch files I create for signing scripts.
I HAVE used it in preference to ShellExecute, but mostly because it can be used in a way to pause your main app, which suits this need specifically.
I sign applications and then zip them up. If the signing process ran independently. I'd probably end up zipping unsigned files. So having the zip process delayed (paused) is a good thing!
I don't particularly want my applications being paused any time I create a new process (start an application). While I believe you don't have to pause your app if you use createProcess. However, the lpCommandLine variable cannot go out of scope (or freed up) as CreateProcess may try to modify it. For this reason I can only see myself using CreateProcess in limited circumstances. 
Since it's also been recommended, I will have a look at ShellExecuteEx next.
Hopefully this code snippet will help someone.
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
//  WinAPI DOCUMENTATION
//  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw
//  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_information
//  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
PROCESS_INFORMATION CreateProcessW_VerySimple                                   ( const UnicodeString& Application_IncludingPath
                                                                                , const UnicodeString& Arguments
                                                                                , const UnicodeString& WorkingDirectory
                                                                                , const bool           WaitForComplete  // I have a default of true
                                                                                )
{
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
//
//  This function will assume CreateProcessW is always the target WinAPI function
//  Despite being told to always put quotes around the application var, this fails for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" ??
//  So DO NOT apply quotes to lpApplicationName.
//
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
//BOOL CreateProcessW( LPCWSTR               lpApplicationName     [in, optional]       | NULL = Get App Name from lpCommandLine
//                                                                                           * app name , with path (assume it's not in the same directory)
//                                                                                           * If no path is supplied the current drive & directory is assumed
//                                                                                           * You MUST supply the file extension (no assumptions will be made)
//                   , LPWSTR                lpCommandLine         [in, out, optional]  | NULL = no arguments
//                                                                                           * Command line can be set as "\"executable\" arg1 arg2 ... argN"
//                                                                                           * DO NOT SUPPLY A READ-ONLY VAR. CreateProcessW *can* modify this!
//                                                                                           *   - function should be blocking (this var must remain in scope)
//                                                                                           * max length is 32,767
//                                                                                           * If including app & path, use "quotes"
//                   , LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes   [in, optional]       | NULL  = Process handle not inheritable
//                   , LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes    [in, optional]       | NULL  = Thread handle not inheritable
//                   , BOOL                  bInheritHandles       [in]                 | FALSE = handles not inheritable
//                   , DWORD                 dwCreationFlags       [in]                 | 0     = No creation flags
//                   , LPVOID                lpEnvironment         [in, optional]       | NULL  = Use parent's environment block
//                   , LPCWSTR               lpCurrentDirectory    [in, optional]       | NULL  = Use parent's starting directory
//                                                                                           * This may NOT require quotation marks
//                   , LPSTARTUPINFOW        lpStartupInfo         [in]                 | Start with empty structure
//                                                                                           * {Left,Top,Width,Height,Visible, etc..}
//                   , LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation  [out]                | ** THE FUNCTION WILL RETURN ME **
//                   );
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
// TO MAKE THIS A 'GENERIC' FUNCTION IT WILL BE NECESSARY TO DECORATE ALL PATH VALUES **BEFORE** SENDING TO THIS FUNCTION
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // SET ALL DEFAULTS
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    LPCWSTR               lpApplicationName    = NULL;
    LPWSTR                lpCommandLine        = NULL;  // not a constant !!
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes  = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes   = NULL;
    BOOL                  bInheritHandles      = FALSE;
    DWORD                 dwCreationFlags      = 0;
    LPVOID                lpEnvironment        = NULL;
    LPCWSTR               lpCurrentDirectory   = NULL;
    STARTUPINFO           StartupInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&StartupInfo, sizeof(StartupInfo));
    StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION   ProcessInformation;
    unsigned long         ProcessReturnValue   = 0;
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // APPLY FUNCTION VARIABLES
    // leave NULL's in place if blank values are received
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    UnicodeString         usApplicationName    = Application_IncludingPath.Trim();
    if (!usApplicationName.IsEmpty())
    {
        // (only) If an application value was supplied
        // apply it to the lpApplicationName variable
        if (!FileExists(usApplicationName))
        {
           // the executable doesn't exits. The request will fail!
           return ProcessInformation;
        };
        lpApplicationName = usApplicationName.w_str();
    };
    UnicodeString         usCommandLine        = Arguments.Trim();            // Sometimes I may need to include quoted paths!!
    if (!usCommandLine.IsEmpty())
    {
        // (only) If an Arguments value was supplied
        // apply it to the lpCommandLine variable
        // Note : Applying this value requires an intermediate variable/type
        std::wstring          wstr(usCommandLine.c_str());                   // !!! STEP 1 !!! Convert std::wstring
        lpCommandLine = const_cast<LPWSTR>(wstr.c_str());                    // !!! STEP 2 !!! Apply to WinAPI variable
        // Note : this variable must persist while the process is running
        // to allow CreateProcessW to write back to it
        // !!! a blocking action will be required to keep this var from going out of scope !!!
    };
    UnicodeString         usCurrentDirectory   = WorkingDirectory.Trim();
    if (!usCurrentDirectory.IsEmpty())
    {
        // Apparently, I do not require quotes :)
        lpCurrentDirectory   = usCurrentDirectory.w_str();
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Start your child process
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    if (!CreateProcessW( lpApplicationName     // LPCWSTR
                       , lpCommandLine         // LPWSTR
                       , lpProcessAttributes   // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                       , lpThreadAttributes    // LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                       , bInheritHandles       // BOOL
                       , dwCreationFlags       // DWORD
                       , lpEnvironment         // LPVOID
                       , lpCurrentDirectory    // LPCWSTR
                       , &StartupInfo          // Pointer to structure : LPSTARTUPINFOW
                       , &ProcessInformation   // Pointer to structure : PROCESS_INFORMATION
                       )
       )
    {
        DWORD         WinAPIError = GetLastError();
        UnicodeString CreateProcessWError = "Could not create child process ("
                                          + UnicodeString(WinAPIError)
                                          + ")";
        throw CreateProcessWError.c_str();
    }
    else
    {
        if (WaitForComplete)
        {
            // this should be the preferred path
            WaitForSingleObject( ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );           // Wait until child process exits
                                                                                    // ** your app will pause (freeze) until the child process returns
            GetExitCodeProcess ( ProcessInformation.hProcess,&ProcessReturnValue);  // I might be able to help with debugging
            CloseHandle( ProcessInformation.hProcess );                             // Close process
            CloseHandle( ProcessInformation.hThread );                              // Close thread handles
        };
    };
    return ProcessInformation;
}
PROCESS_INFORMATION CreateProcessW__Blocking_RunBatchFile                       ( const UnicodeString& BatchFile_IncludingPath
                                                                                , const UnicodeString& WorkingDirectory
                                                                                )
{
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
//
//  This function will 'specialiase' in running batch files through the command line
//  It will make use of the Generic Function and feed it some **fixed** values
//
//*************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    return CreateProcessW_VerySimple  ( L"C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"                            // const UnicodeString& Application_WithPath
                                      , L"/C " + PathString_AddQuotes ( BatchFile_IncludingPath )    // const UnicodeString& Arguments
                                      , WorkingDirectory                                             // const UnicodeString& WorkingDirectory
                                      , true                                                         // const bool           WaitForComplete
                                      );
}


In your call to OpenApplication, are you really passing the arguments in the correct order? The string "InetMgr.exe" doesn't look like a Location, and "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\" doesn't look like a FileName. Besides, the path needs to escape the backslashes or use forward slashes. In fact, your compiler should be giving you errors. Which means that you're not showing us a proper [mre].

my bad, something else calls OpenApplication having "split" a single path+App String. I will update this

Is ShellExecute() returning an error? Consider using ShellExecuteEx() instead to get more reliable error codes. But why are you using ShellExecute() at all to run an .exe instead of using CreateProcess() directly? Also, is your app 32bit or 64bit? Maybe you are running into an issue with the File System Redirector?

Remember that C++ string literals treat \  as an escape character.  Often bites filenames.  If you want backslashes in your string, you need to double them up "C:\\dir\\file"

Or use Raw String literals in C++11 and later, ie: R"(C:\dir\file)"

@RemyLebeau: Good option if using a modern compiler, might not be available to this OP

values with single \ are copies from the dubugger. I will be sending \
I'm using ShellExecute because I've a lot to learn. This code has always worked before so never had a need to look at anything else.
I will now be looking at

Raw strings as \ always annoys me
CreateProcess

The app is 32bit. I can't use the clang compiler yet so I'm barred from 64bit for now

That's why we need a [mre], to see some actual code replicating the actual problem.

ShellExecuteA  is a weid way to execute program which might be not supported for some service-like programs (which IIS clearly is) or mixing 32-bit \64bit executables. To run a program, use CreateProcess. To open (or use other supported verb) a document file with a shell association, use ShellExecute

Thanks for the explanation Swift. I'm often told I do things in a weird way. It's likely because I've never had any training in C++, not even a little. Anything I've learnt, I've learnt by solving problems. Usually the first solution will do, until it doesn't, then I learn some more.
ShellExecute is just something I got working years ago and have never needed to replace. I've been looking at CreateProcess since Remy mentioned it as I want this to be an opportunity to learn.
Some day I will know the best way to do things. Until then, advice from people like yourselves is appreciated :)

OK, so I was doing some research into other things and lucked on to the real answer to my question.
ShellExecuteA sometimes does not complete an action ... if you are asking it to open a file under System32.
Windows has Automatic File system redirection built in to try and cope with some of the vagaries of 64 bit windows. So when you request something under system32 it diverts you to SysWOW64.
to get around this issue, there's a couple of additional functions to be aware of.

Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
see : [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection]


...and here's some code that works on my Win 10 (64 bit) machine.
{
    PVOID OldValue = NULL;
    if( Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue) )
    {
        HINSTANCE AppHandle = ShellExecuteA( NULL 
                                           , "open"                                        
                                           , "C:\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\InetMgr.exe" 
                                           , ""
                                           , ""
                                           , SW_SHOWNORMAL
                                           );
        if ( FALSE == Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue) )
        {
            //  Failure to re-enable redirection should be considered
            //  a critical failure and execution aborted.
            return;
        };
    }
}

In all likelihood. The original function I was using will work just fine if I apply similar changes :) ... but this can wait till tomorrow
Thank you everyone for your help & support & idea's. (I will indeed be researching a few things that have been suggested)
